# R linear model category to dummy variables

Tags: r

I have an R linear model that created 7 dummy variables from a factor with 8 levels. I understand why there is 7 variables, but I don't understand how to relate them back to the original data's levels based on their names. What do the extensions .L .Q .C ^4 ^5 and ^6 mean?

```
quality.L
quality.Q
quality.C
quality^4
quality^5
quality^6
```

I am trying to convert the fitted model to an executable formula in Ruby so I can run predictions in Rails after the model is built in R.

Comment: You get this if your factor is an **ordered** factor. Did you want this? The extensions are then L=Linear, Q=Quadratic, C=Cubic, then ^4 is fourth power and so on. If your factor isn't really an ordered factor, then recreate your data with an unordered factor and you should get results based on one level as baseline.

Comment: They are quality levels are like; Low, Fair, Average, Good, Excellent so it seems appropriate to be ordered unless it adds more complexity than is warranted.

Comment: Spacedman is referring to R classes, not to types of variables in a statistical sense. Objects of class `"ordered"` and `"factor"` are treated differently in model-fitting. See `? ordered`. You probably want factor variables, not ordered.

Comment: Interesting, I just assumed ordering would be better.  I'll go back and try it without ordering.

Comment: Thanks Spacedman and Thomas!

Comment: You are probably right to leave it as ordered. There's some discussion about ordered factor level model parameters here http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/07180efc6h/r-contrasts-for-ordered-factors - its all done via orthogonal polynomials.